# Sending input value to click handler in React

Tags: reactjs

I have an input number value which I'm trying to send to my clickHandler but I've done something wrong ...

On click I want to send the value "this.state.NumberHolder" to the handler

```
<input value={this.state.NumberHolder} onClick={this.clickHandler} type="number" />
```

Doing a console.log I can see that my clickHandler is being called but I'm not getting the updated state value

```
clickHandler = (target) => {
  console.log("targetHere", target);
  this.setState({
    NumberHolder: target.value
  });
};
```

Comment: What do you expect ? apparently, on click of the input, you read the value and set it back to the input, i think we miss a bit of code to understand…

Comment: Hey @Romain - so it's a number input, so if I typed "1" in the input field I'd expect my console log to return "1"

Comment: then don't you want to log : `console.log("targetHere", target.value);` ? And use `onChange={this.clickHandler}` instead of `onClick={this.clickHandler}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you receive by default property is the context of the event.

So, to handle correctly the value of the input tag, you need to do this:

```
clickHandler = (event) => {
  console.log("targetHere", event.target);
  this.setState({
    NumberHolder: event.target.value
  });
};
```

And there is a big issue with your JSX, `onClick` is executed when the input is clicked, not changed. So, you will never receive the new input value. **Use on change**:

```
<input value={this.state.NumberHolder} onChange={this.clickHandler} type="number" />
```

And this should work perfectly. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/ub3Loq62/) to see it working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be like this:

```
// destructure target from the event object by wrapping it in braces
clickHandler = ({target}) => {
  console.log("targetHere", target);
  this.setState({
    NumberHolder: target.value
  });
};
```

But there is a bigger issue with your code.  Since the value of your input will always be this.state.NumberHolder, you are simply setting the same value over and over again.

If you have a particular value you want to send on the click event, you can turn your click event into a curried function like this:

```
// pass in number as first argument to function that returns another anonymous function
clickHandler = (NumberHolder) => () =>{
  this.setState({ NumberHolder });
};
```

And then on the element with the click event, pass the onClick like this:

```
<input onClick={this.clickHandler(3)} />
```

That will pass the argument in scope of the function, and allow you to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comments, i believe you want to add the event on change of the `input` and log the value entered like this:

```html
<input value={this.state.NumberHolder} onChange={this.clickHandler} type="number" />
```

```
clickHandler = (target) => {
  console.log("target Value", target.value);
  this.setState({
    NumberHolder: target.value
  });
};
```